# Mobx textField's attribute value doesn't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have **TextFields** from *material-ui*. On value change I assign the value to **model.data**. **Model** is mobx **FormStore**. In console as you can see the value changes, but input fields don't have any characters when I type. Why does the **TextField's** attribute value doesn't change even though model.data changes?
[image]

Comment: Can you please post a functioning code sample? It's near impossible to give you an answer without seeing how your code is setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding properties to observable object after it was created will not make added properties observable. You need to use `extendObservable()` instead of assigning new properties directly to observable object. Another solution is to use observable map instead. Note that properties added through `extendObservable()` will not get picked up if the component is being rendered in a loop.

`extendObservable(model.data, {[e.target.name]: e.target.value})`

[Read official document here](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/extend-observable.html)

Comment: Do I have to extend observable everytime in onChange function? That doesn't seem right. Outside the function e is not defined.

Comment: I figured it out, you just have to extendObservable model.data with TextField value properties. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
extendObservable(model.data, {
  name: '',
  lastName: '',
  phone: '',
  skype: '',
  slack: '',
  linkedIn: '',
});
```

Seems to work as the properties in the observable object are not observable. You need to use extendObservable.